# how to fix "bash: flutter: command not found" error?

Tags: bash, flutter, visual-studio-code, upgrade

I have been working on flutter using VScode with all environment variables set on Windows OS. Now i upgraded the flutter using "flutter upgrade" in Git Bash terminal of VScode to the stable version and now i am not able to use flutter commands in Git Bash terminal of VScode. I wonder where things could have gone wrong , how do i fix it ?

I re-verified that all my environment variables are set correctly according to official documentation. Also flutter commands are running perfectly through flutter console .

```
Ashish@DESKTOP-3JFCI3M MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Flutter Exercise/test_2
$ flutter doctor
bash: flutter: command not found
```

**Edit**: Made changes to the  "~/.bash_profile" as mentioned by Sam , still getting the same error . Also i re-checked and the environment variables are set there already. Any ideas what i could do further to fix it ? Thanks in Advance :)
Also when executed command of step no 3. `source ~/.bash_profile` , output is

````
$ source ~/.bash_profile
bash: C:DEVLOPMENTflutterbin: command not found
bash: C:DEVLOPMENTflutterbincachedart-sdkbin: command not found```
````

Comment: There, write `echo %PATH%`. That will give you a list of directories. One of them needs to contain flutter.bat for flutter to work. Maybe if you changed your path variable recently, a reboot maybe a sure way to apply that.

Comment: @GazihanAlankus He's using Git Bash and you've given him a Windows command prompt command. To see it, he'd need to do `echo $PATH`

Comment: The final message indicates that you have backslashes instead of forward slashes. This makes sense on Windows, but the backslash is a metacharacter in Bash, so you need to single-quote the string with backslashes, or escape each backslash with another backslash. But even Windows itself accepts forward slashes instead so probably that's the simplest fix. (Tempted to suggest ditching Windows as even simpler in the long run.)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that the environment variable, that was previously set, got cleared at some point and that's why the Flutter command is not recognized.

In any case, one way to make sure that Flutter is in your profile is to add it to your path within your `~/.bash_profile` (bash profile) file. The `~/.bash_profile` is a script gets executed every time you open Git Bash.

**Adding Flutter to your Bash Profile**

1. Open your `~/.bash_profile` file for editing:

```sh
$ nano ~/.bash_profile
```

2. Add to the top of your `~/.bash_profile` file, the following lines:

```sh
# Add Flutter to PATH
PATH=/path/to/flutter/bin:$PATH

# Add Dart to PATH
PATH=/path/to/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:$PATH
```

> Replace `/path/to/flutter`, with the absolute path of your Flutter installation directory.

3. Apply the changes:

```sh
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

**Ensuring Git Bash is opened for non-login shells**
(Credit: Charles Duffy)

```sh
$ echo "source ~/.bash_profile" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Opened for every *login* shell. Not every interactive shell is a login shell. You'd want to have your `.bashrc` source `.bash_profile` to make sure it's run for both types.

Comment: And BTW, there's no point to re-`export`ing something that's already in the environment. Just `PATH=/path/to/flutter/bin:$PATH` will have the same effect.

Comment: Updated @CharlesDuffy - though I'm fairly certain Git Bash always opens a login shell.

Comment: please mark as the right answer if this helped.